# What does these versions name in AOSP source tree means?

Tags: android, android-studio, version-control, android-source, custom-rom

I am building a custom rom from AOSP source code

I first decided to edit some AOSP apps from AOSP source tree by downloading and importing to Android Studio

I selected ExactCalculator for training

But I confused by confusing branch names in AOSP tree . I tried downloading pie release version of ExactCalcuator but can't find which Pie branch is latest

Below is the screenshot :: 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/ExactCalculator/+refs
[image]

> I can't understand what is this ...
>   b4s4,cts,cuttlefish,dr1,gsi,grpc,platform release.... etc
>
> To be precise , I need the latest version of Pie running in our
>   Android phones

Please make me to understand this branches of a release ....

Comment: Btw, it's not "ASOP", it's "AOSP" as in Android Open Source Project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would pick a branch or tag for the whole AOSP and use the corresponding branch/tag in the `ExactCalculator` sub-repository as well.

```sh
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b pie-release
```

The `.repo/manifest.xml` (a symlink to [default.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+/refs/heads/pie-release/default.xml)) determines which branch or tag is used in `ExactCalculator`. Since the default.xml [does not](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+/refs/heads/pie-release/default.xml#523) specify a different branch/tag name for `ExactCalculator` the default one is being used, which is `pie-release` as well [at the moment](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+/refs/heads/pie-release/default.xml#7).

> Please make me to understand this branches of a release ....

I think you need to contact Google directly for clarification of the branch meanings. I suspect that it is just different teams working on different branches.

> To be precise , I need the latest version of Pie running in our Android phones

I use `pie-release` for the latest release version and `pie-dev` for the latest development version.

Comment: please answer this also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57871822/how-to-add-external-libraries-such-as-retrofit-and-butterknife-in-android-source