# How to add external libraries such as Retrofit and butterknife in Android Source code packages?

Tags: java, android, makefile, android-gradle-plugin, android-source

I am building a custom rom from AOSP source code

I first decided to edit some AOSP apps from AOSP source tree by downloading and importing to Android Studio

I selected ExactCalculator for training

But the AOSP don't have Build.gradle to add my dependencies .

I added some material components and also `Retrofit ,Gson, Butterknife and dagger 2` in Android Studio built.gradle and implemented currency converter via an API in AOSP stock Exact Calculator

Now I overwritten the packaage src folder in AOSP with my modified srcs

But now my doubt is , since packages in AOSP source code don't have build.gradle only Android.mk, how can I add this libraries for building the AOSP source?

Answer (score 1):

Libraries that shall be built inside the AOSP need to have an Android build configuration. Since Android 8 that would be an `Android.bp` file for [Soong](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/) (`Android.mk` files are still supported for now though).

Dagger2 seems to be already integrated: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/dagger2/
You could just add it to your repo manifest to include it in your AOSP.

An alternative to creating Android build configurations is to include prebuilt binaries. But you will have to figure out whether that is technically and legally possible for your use-case.

Comment: do you have any tutorial link that teaches about how to do this ?

Comment: No, unfortunately the documentation of Soong is quite poor. What I do is searching for similar `platform/external/` projects in https://android.googlesource.com/ and trying to understand what they did in order to port for Android.